# Providing better WSDL from C# SOAP

Tags: c#, soap, xsd, xml-serialization, wsdl

I'm pulling together some services in C# that have to match specific data format; e.g. string lengths, various enumerations and formatting.  I have the back-up approach to validate post the SOAP call and respond with friendly messages and pre-defined error codes, but I would like to place additional information into the WDSL (so it is clear that field x can only be 15 alpha characters only with no numbers or punctuation for example).

Is this possible, if so are there any examples and or tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a SOAP message, generate a XSD out of it, and then edit the XSD until all your validation things are in there. Provide the XSD along with the WSDL to your customer.

When you both validate the messages using the same XSD the problem should be gone.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be aware that .NET does not validate SOAP messages against the schema in a WSDL. For instance, if part of your input message shows a maxLength of 50, there will be no error or exception when you are sent 51 instead.

Second, it is not possible to adjust your classes in such a way that you can control the exact schema. For instance, you cannot cause a maxLength attribute into the WSDL.

Third, if you *must* completely control the WSDL, then you need to write it by hand. You will never have complete control over the WSDL that .NET generates.

Finally, you seen to be talking about ASMX web services here. You should not be using ASMX web services for new development - they have been replaced with WCF.